# Including and updating of pdf_tex files from svg with inkscape in directory of choice

Tags: graphics, svg, workflow, inkscape

I'm working on a way to have my .svg exported with inkscape to `.pdf_tex` if the `.svg` file was changed. That allows me to change the figure, hit Ctrl+S and then just compile my tex file.

I adapted some commands which I found [here](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) so that I can access my figures anywhere (previously it was only working with the working directory).

Now to make it easier to use, I'd like to just declare `\graphicspath`   and then have my commands use it.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
\newcommand{\figurepath}[1]{D:/figures/#1}
```

which I can then use in my own command like

```
\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{
\input{\figurepath{#1.pdf_tex}}
}
```

Now how do I get my `\figurepath` to use `\graphicspath`? Is there something like get(grahicspath)?

**Edit:**

Okay, so here is what I'm working with at the moment:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,import,xcolor,transparent}


\newcommand{\figurepath}[1]{path/to/svgs/#1}

\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}
  {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0
  {\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi
}


\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
  \executeiffilenewer{\figurepath{#1.svg}}{\figurepath{#1.pdf}}
  {inkscape -z -D --file=\figurepath{#1.svg} 
  --export-pdf=\figurepath{#1.pdf} --export-latex}
  \input{\figurepath{#1.pdf_tex}}%
}
```

It runs and is quite useful. What it does is check if the `svg` file has been edited and if yes it exports a new `pdf_tex` with inkscape. There are some other examples around which do the same, but they all worked only for `svg`s in the working directory. I couldn't find one where it is possible to use `svg`s from any location on your computer.

In order for this to work, it is necessary to add `-shell-escape` to `pdflatex`, e. g. I'm using Texstudio and under Options->Commands I edited the line PdfLaTex to look like

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Under Windows it is also required to add the location of inkscape.exe to PATH. To do this type `System` in the search panel and then go to `advanced system settings`. Under `advanced` click `Environment Variables...` and a window will pop up, find PATH in `system variables`, click edit and add the directory of inkscape.

There is a known bug with the 0.48 versions of inkscape, which will print

```
 RegistryTool: Could not set the value 'Path/to/inkscape'
```

nevertheless it works and this bug has been fixed in the 0.91 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original LaTeX code found on page 3 of [this document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf), on which your question seems to be based on, requires the packages `graphicx.sty` and `color.sty` (or `xcolor.sty`) to work.

A slightly different approach is to make additional use of the package `import.sty`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,import,xcolor}

\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp%
    {\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
    {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}%
    >0%
    {\immediate\write18{#3}}%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\includesvg}[2][]{%
  \executeiffilenewer{#1#2.svg}{#1#2.pdf}%
    {inkscape -z -D --file=#1#2.svg --export-pdf=#1#2.pdf --export-latex}%
  \subimport{#1}{#2.pdf_tex}%
}
```

Now `\includesvg` has an optional argument which accepts the *relative path* to the files (note that all three files, i.e. `.PDF`, `.PDF_TEX`, and `.SVG`, must have the same name and be present in the same directory).

Examples of usage:

```
\includesvg[figures/]{mydwg}
\includesvg{mydwg} % working directory
\includesvg[../figures/aero/]{mydwg}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's the other way round:-)
the path mechanism is implemented for `\input` and `\includegraphics` locally sets it to the value given in `\graphicspath` .

So most efficient is don't use `\graphicspath` just set

```
TEXINPUTS="D:/work/figures;"
```

before you run latex which will add that folder to the start of the search path.

Or, if you want to use the `\graphicspath` notation but have `\input` see it,  use

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{D:/work/figures/}}
\makeatother
```